# categorical description of the Minkowski sum of polytopes

Tags: category-theory, euclidean-geometry, polyhedra, affine-geometry, polytopes

Consider the category $\textbf{Poly}$ of polytopes, where the objects are convex hulls of finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ for arbitrary $d \in \mathbb{N}$ and where the morphisms are affine maps (i.e. maps, which can be extended to affine maps between the whole euclidean spaces). The Minkowski sum of two polytopes $P,Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is defined as $P + Q := \{ p+q : p \in P, q \in Q \}$, which is again a polytope.

Is there any categorical description of $P+Q$ as limit or colimit in $\textbf{Poly}$?

Edit: As it seems that there is no such description in that general situation, let us change the category and consider only polytopes which are centered at the origin and linear maps. Does it change anything?

Comment: I doubt so, as far as I can tell, there is no (categorical) way to decide weather two polytopes live in the same ambient space $\mathbb{R}^d$, so I find it unlikely to find a (co)limit construction that respects that property. But my knowledge about polytopes and affine maps is pretty limited, so... (Did you have a look at this thesis: http://people.reed.edu/~davidp/homepage/students/valby.pdf ?)

Comment: @roman: Note that if we were talking about the sum of subspaces in some category of $K$-vector-spaces, there would be such a description: $U+V$ is just the pushout of $U \cap V \to U$ and $U \cap V \to V$. Yet, from the categorical point of view we cannot decide in which ambient spaces $U,V$ and $U \cap V$ live. That thesis is known to me, but unfortunately the Minkowski sum is not dealt with there.