# "point-free" definition of MInkowski sum?

Tags: category-theory, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, universal-property

Fix an integer $n$, and consider the category $Conv$ of all convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, with morphisms given by inclusion. Given $A,B\in Obj(C)$, the Minkowski sum is defined as $A+B=\{a+b: a\in A, b\in B\}$.

Question: does $A+B$ satisfy a universal property in $Conv$?

If not, then is there an "intrinsic" definition of $A+B$? 
By "intrinsic", I mean that the definition can be expressed entirely in terms of operations on convex sets, and does not explicitly require quantification over points of $A$ and $B$. An example a definition I would consider "intrinsic" is $ConvHull(A)=\cap\{A': A\subset A', A' convex\}$.

(This is NOT a duplicate of
[categorical description of the Minkowski sum of polytopes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556697/categorical-description-of-the-minkowski-sum-of-polytopes) because that question deals with a different categorical structure on the space of convex sets)

Comment: This category seems rather poor: in general we don't even have an arrow $A\to A+B$..

Comment: @ Berci, that is a good point, I am not sure whether this category is the correct one to consider